# pan/zoom of pyqtgraph in pyqt5 not responding even with threading

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, threadpool, pyqtgraph

I've made a PyQt5 GUI which plots the last of several scans from a RGA.  I'd like the user to be able to zoom/pan the existing plots while the next scan is being acquired and am trying to use threading to keep the GUI responsive while the serial communication is being done.  That's not quite working.  I have made a simpler version of the code, with a while loop to mimic the pause during data acquisition.  As well, I'm finding that I have to put QApplication.processevents() within my thread to get the plot to update at the end of each loop within the thread - otherwise it only updates with the final plots after the thread is done.  Which seems to defeat the purpose.

I also have a stop button I would like to interrupt everything that seems to lag in response similar to the pan/zoom on the graph.

Any help would be appreciated!

The UI file with the pyqtgraph added as PlotWidget is (apologies - more complicated than necessary as it is a pared-down version of my original) ThreadingLayout.ui :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1126</width>
    <height>738</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_6">
      <item>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_16">
        <property name="sizeConstraint">
         <enum>QLayout::SetFixedSize</enum>
        </property>
        <item>
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_4">
            <item>
             <widget class="QPushButton" name="startbutton">
              <property name="text">
               <string>Start</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QPushButton" name="stopbutton">
              <property name="text">
               <string>Stop</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
      <item>
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_5">
        <item>
         <widget class="PlotWidget" name="plotWidget" native="true">
          <property name="sizePolicy">
           <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Preferred">
            <horstretch>0</horstretch>
            <verstretch>0</verstretch>
           </sizepolicy>
          </property>
          <property name="minimumSize">
           <size>
            <width>0</width>
            <height>300</height>
           </size>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3"/>
        </item>
        <item>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_17">
          <property name="spacing">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <item>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="exitbutton">
            <property name="sizePolicy">
             <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
              <horstretch>0</horstretch>
              <verstretch>0</verstretch>
             </sizepolicy>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>Exit</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1126</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>PlotWidget</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header location="global">pyqtgraph</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
 <buttongroups>
  <buttongroup name="buttonGroup_2"/>
  <buttongroup name="buttonGroup"/>
 </buttongroups>
</ui>
```

and my python3 code is:

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import pyqtgraph as pg
from random import random
import numpy as np
import traceback, sys


class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    error = pyqtSignal(tuple)
    result = pyqtSignal(object)
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)


class Worker(QRunnable):

    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

        # Store constructor arguments (re-used for processing)
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()

        # Add the callback to our kwargs
        self.kwargs['progress_callback'] = self.signals.progress

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        try:
            result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
            self.signals.error.emit((exctype, value, traceback.format_exc()))
        else:
            self.signals.result.emit(result)  # Return the result of the processing
        finally:
            self.signals.finished.emit()  # Done


class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()

        uic.loadUi("ThreadingLayout.ui", self)

        self.startButton = self.findChild(QPushButton, "startbutton")
        self.stopButton = self.findChild(QPushButton, "stopbutton")
        self.exitButton = self.findChild(QPushButton, "exitbutton")
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.clickedstartButton)
        self.stopButton.clicked.connect(self.clickedstopButton)
        self.exitButton.clicked.connect(self.clickedexitButton)

        self.numberstartclicks=0
        self.numberstopclicks=0

        self.show()

        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()


    def clickedstopButton(self):
        self.numberstopclicks = self.numberstopclicks+1


    def plotanddelay(self):
        self.plotWidget.clear()

        try:
            self.legend.scene().removeItem(self.legend)
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        self.legend = self.plotWidget.addLegend()

        self.singlerunx = list(range(100))
        self.singleruny = []
        randomscaling = random()
        for i in range(100):
            self.singleruny.append(randomscaling * self.singlerunx[i] + random())

        self.allrunsy = np.append(self.allrunsy, self.singleruny)

        # only plot last 4 plots
        if self.plotrunindex < self.numberplotlines:
            for self.plotlineindex in reversed(range(self.plotrunindex)):
                pen = pg.mkPen(color=pg.intColor(self.plotlineindex), width=2)
                ploty = self.allrunsy[len(self.allrunsy) - len(self.singlerunx) * (self.plotlineindex + 1):
                                      len(self.allrunsy) - len(self.singlerunx) * self.plotlineindex]
                self.plotWidget.plot(self.singlerunx, ploty, pen=pen,
                                     name='Run ' + str(self.plotrunindex - self.plotlineindex))
        else:
            for plotlineindex in reversed(range(self.numberplotlines)):
                pen = pg.mkPen(color=pg.intColor(plotlineindex), width=2)
                ploty = self.allrunsy[len(self.allrunsy) - len(self.singlerunx) * (plotlineindex + 1):
                                      len(self.allrunsy) - len(self.singlerunx) * plotlineindex]
                self.plotWidget.plot(self.singlerunx, ploty, pen=pen,
                                     name='Run ' + str(self.plotrunindex - plotlineindex))

        self.plotWidget.showGrid(True, True)

        QApplication.processEvents()
        # put in time delay
        while i < 2E7:
             i = i+1


    def clickedstartButton(self):
        self.numberstartclicks = self.numberstartclicks+1

        if (self.numberstartclicks==1):
            self.plotWidget.clear()

            try:
                self.legend.scene().removeItem(self.legend)
            except Exception as e:
                pass
            self.legend = self.plotWidget.addLegend()

            self.allrusnx = []
            self.allrunsy = []
            self.numberruns = 10
            self.numberplotlines = 3

            for self.plotrunindex in range(self.numberruns):
                if self.numberstopclicks > 0:
                    print('Run stopped by user')
                    self.numberstopclicks = 0
                    break

                worker = Worker(self.plotanddelay())
                # Execute
                self.threadpool.start(worker)

        else:
            self.numberstartclicks = 0


    def clickedexitButton(self):
        self.close()


app=QApplication([])
UIWindow=UI()
app.exec()
```

Just an update - based on the useful information from Luke, I found the following code did the trick:

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import pyqtgraph as pg
from random import random
import numpy as np


class ConfWorker(QThread):
    threadSignal = pyqtSignal(list)
    finishSignal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, startParm):
        super().__init__()
        self.startParm = startParm   # Initialize the parameters passed to the task


    def run(self):
        for i in range(self.startParm):
            if (self.isInterruptionRequested()):
                return
            self.singlerunx = list(range(100))
            returndata=[]
            singleruny = []
            randomscaling = random()
            for j in range(100):
                 singleruny.append(randomscaling * self.singlerunx[j] + random())
            returndata.append(i)  #gives the run number
            returndata.append(singleruny)
            self.threadSignal.emit(returndata)
            QThread.msleep(2000)
        self.finishSignal.emit('finished')


class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()

        uic.loadUi("ThreadingLayout.ui", self)

        self.startButton = self.findChild(QPushButton, "startbutton")
        self.stopButton = self.findChild(QPushButton, "stopbutton")
        self.exitButton = self.findChild(QPushButton, "exitbutton")
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.workerStart)
        self.stopButton.clicked.connect(self.clickedstopButton)
        self.exitButton.clicked.connect(self.clickedexitButton)

        self.numberstartclicks=0
        self.numberstopclicks=0
        self.singlerunx=[]
        self.singleruny=[]
        self.allrunsx=[]
        self.allrunsy=[]
        self.threadrunindex=0
        self.startParm=0

        self.show()


    def clickedstopButton(self):
        self.worker.requestInterruption()
        print('stopped')

    def updateplot(self, returndata):
        self.plotWidget.clear()

        self.plotrunindex=returndata[0]
        self.allrunsy = np.append(self.allrunsy, returndata[1:])
        self.singlerunx = list(range(100))

        try:
            self.legend.scene().removeItem(self.legend)
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        self.legend = self.plotWidget.addLegend()

        # only plot last 4 plots
        if self.plotrunindex < self.numberplotlines:
            for self.plotlineindex in reversed(range(self.plotrunindex)):
                pen = pg.mkPen(color=pg.intColor(self.plotlineindex), width=2)
                ploty = self.allrunsy[len(self.allrunsy) - len(self.singlerunx) * (self.plotlineindex + 1):
                                       len(self.allrunsy) - len(self.singlerunx) * self.plotlineindex]
                self.plotWidget.plot(self.singlerunx, ploty, pen=pen,
                                     name='Run ' + str(self.plotrunindex - self.plotlineindex))
        else:
            for self.plotlineindex in reversed(range(self.numberplotlines)):
                pen = pg.mkPen(color=pg.intColor(self.plotlineindex), width=2)
                ploty = self.allrunsy[len(self.allrunsy) - len(self.singlerunx) * (self.plotlineindex + 1):
                                       len(self.allrunsy) - len(self.singlerunx) * self.plotlineindex]
                self.plotWidget.plot(self.singlerunx, ploty, pen=pen,
                                     name='Run ' + str(self.plotrunindex - self.plotlineindex))

        self.plotWidget.showGrid(True, True)


    def clickedexitButton(self):
        self.close()


    def workerStart(self):
        self.numberstartclicks = self.numberstartclicks + 1

        if (self.numberstartclicks == 1):
            self.plotWidget.clear()

            try:
                self.legend.scene().removeItem(self.legend)
            except Exception as e:
                pass
            self.legend = self.plotWidget.addLegend()

            self.allrusnx = []
            self.allrunsy = []
            self.numberruns = 10
            self.numberplotlines = 3

            self.plotrunindex = 0
            self.startParm = self.numberruns

            self.worker = ConfWorker(self.startParm)
            self.worker.threadSignal.connect(self.updateplot)
            self.worker.finishSignal.connect(self.on_finishSignal)
            self.worker.start()

        else:
            self.numberstartclicks = 0


    def on_finishSignal(self, text):
        print(text)


app=QApplication([])
UIWindow=UI()
app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in this line:

```
worker = Worker(self.plotanddelay())
```

1. This line directly calls `plotanddelay()`, which means that when the start button is clicked, it immediately goes into this loop and calls `plotanddelay` repeatedly without going back to the Qt event loop. That's why the GUI locks up, and why it was necessary for you to add `processEvents()`; this allows you to manually process those events (but shouldn't be necessary).
2. Your QRunnable class expects a function to run as its first argument, but you are sending it the output of `plotanddelay()`, which is `None`. So that means your background threads aren't doing this work at all.
3. Background threads in Qt are not allowed to do any GUI work anyway; so even if you got your background thread to run `plotanddelay` like you intended, it's likely this program would just crash.

So to fix this you need your background threads to be doing all of the slow, non-GUI work (like acquiring data from your RGA), and then your main GUI thread does all of the plotting work. This could be on a timer, so that the plots are updating regularly regardless of whether data has arrived, or you could have the background thread send a signal indicating when new data has arrived.

Comment: Thanks - that was really helpful and pushed me in the direction I needed to go.  I now have something running how I would like.  I'll try to modify the code above to show what I did to get it working in case someone else comes across this question.